# XML does marshal properly, does not unmarshal because XML doc is declared invalid

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to  re-read an XML file generated by my Java program and provide a graphical representation of it in a `JTable` form. The generated XML, manually, conforms to the schema however the program detects it as invalid.

The logic is simple:
1. Check if the `task-list.xml` and `task-list-schema.xsd` exist.
2. if **yes**, unmarshall the XML, prepare rows using data from XML document, add rows to table.
3. if **no**, prepare a  blank GUI.

The problem is that the XML does not conform to the schema. The problem is not in the generated XML or the schema **it is in the classes used for binding**. Here is how they are:

```
FormatList
|->Vector<Format>

TaskList
|-> Vector<Task>

Task
|-> input xs:string
|-> output xs:string
|-> Format 
|-> taskID xs:integer
|-> isReady xs:boolean  

Format
|-> name xs:string
|-> width xs:string
|-> height xs:string
|-> extension xs:string
```

So, `FormatList` and `Task` both share the same class `Format` because each video conversion task has an associated format with it.

Here is the error I get:
[image]

Here is the generated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<task-list>
    <task>
        <input>E:\Videos\AutoIT\AutoIt Coding Tutorial Two - Website Functions.flv</input>
        <output>E:\test\StandaloneVideoConverter</output>
        <format>
            <name>[AVI] HD 1080p</name>
            <width>1920</width>
            <height>1080</height>
            <extension>.avi</extension>
        </format>
        <taskID>3</taskID>
        <isReady>false</isReady>
    </task>
</task-list>
```

**How do I solve this?**

### Classes

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Format {
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name="width")
    private int width;
    @XmlElement(name="height")
    private int height;
    @XmlElement(name="extension")
    private String extension;

    //getters and setters, synchronized
}

@XmlRootElement(name="format-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FormatList {
    @XmlElement(name="format")
    private Vector<Format> formats;


    public Vector<Format> getFormats(){
        return formats;
    }
    // this is the complete class
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Task {
    @XmlElement(name="input")
    private String input;   // String representing the input file
    @XmlElement(name="output")
    private String output; // String representing the output file
    @XmlElement(name="format")
    private Format format; // a jaxb.classes.Format representing the format of conversion
    @XmlElement(name="taskID")
    private long taskID; // a unique ID for each task.
    @XmlElement(name="isReady")
    private boolean isReady; // boolean value representing whether the task is ready for conversion

    @XmlTransient
    private boolean isChanging = false; // boolean representing if the user is changing the task DO NOT MARSHALL
    @XmlTransient
    private boolean isExecuting = false; // boolean representing whether the task is being executed  DO NOT MARSHALL



    // getters and setters, synchronized
}

@XmlRootElement(name="task-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TaskList {

    public TaskList(){
        tasks = new Vector<Task>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name="task")
    Vector<Task> tasks;

    public Vector<Task> getTasks(){
        return tasks;
    }

    // this is  the complete class

}
```

Comment: If any other information is needed, let me know :)

Comment: Can you provide the classes?

Comment: Done as requested. To clear the clutter, I have excluded the getter and setter methods :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the classes.  The answer given by @RyanStewart appears to be the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't seem to match the XML you posted. That error is saying that JAXB is attempting to unmarshal a `format-list` element but doesn't know what to do with it. There's no `format-list` in that XML. From the given error, I'd expect that you have code like this:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(TaskList.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);
```

and you're giving it FormatList XML instead of TaskList XML as input.